# Passing Unsigned Long Long to pthread_create by reference

Tags: c, casting, type-conversion, pthreads

If I wanted to pass an unsigned long long to a pthread_create function call, how would I do this? I understand that due to pthread_create having void * as the last argument means that there are opportunities for type safety issues to arise.

I've seen it done like this with integers:

```
int i = 0;
pthread_create(..., ..., ..., (void *)&i);
```

And then the int is dereferenced within the function that the thread executes. Would the same work if "i" was an unsigned long long type? Basically what I want to do is get the thread id of the thread in an unsigned long long variable using gettid(). Thank you for your help!

Comment: yes. you can pass a pointer to anything, as long as the start routine that you also passed as on the same wavelength, and casts it back.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the type is. A pointer to a variable is a pointer to a variable. Another matter is what happens with the variable after you call `pthread_create`... If it is, for example, a `for` loop iterator variable, that you change in the loop, then the value will change in all threads you passed a pointer to. There's a "trick" here, that can pass values through clever casting: `(void *)(uintptr_t) i`. Then do the opposite in the thread: `int i = (int)(uintptr_t) pi;`

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: `gettid()` returns `pid_t` not `unsigned long long`.

Comment: Yes, but unsigned long long should be guaranteed to be able to hold it.

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention but portability isn't much of an issue. I'm specifically targeting Linux systems.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, generalizing the problem helps to see the solution. Casting an `int` to a `void *` is an old trick to try and avoid memory allocation. Sometimes you just want to configure the thread that will run with more than just an int.

A common approach I use to configure pthreads is to `calloc` some structure, or even the space for a single value (e.g. an `unsigned long long`), pass it to the pthread arg and consume it in my thread function before the `while (1)` of the main thread logic, then `free`.

This allows you to pass as much or little as you want, is always OK no matter the size of what you pass in, and doesn't try to shove values in pointers.

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned long long large_serial_number;
    const char *my_name;
    pthread_t caller_thread;
} fun_thread_args_t;

static void* _fun_thread_run(void *arg) {
    // Get our thread args from the dynamically allocated thread args passed-in
    fun_thread_args_t *thread_args = (fun_thread_args_t *)arg;

    bool done = false;
    while (!done) {
        // Use args here in your thread loop
        ...
    }

    // Free incoming args pointer before exiting the thread loop.
    free(arg);
    return NULL;
}

static pthread_t *_launch_fun_thread(pthread_t *thread, unsigned long long serial_number, const char *name) {
    // TODO: Of course, error-handle all the return values properly ;)

    // Allocate and prepare args for the thread
    fun_thread_args_t *args = calloc(1, sizeof(args));

    args->caller_thread = pthread_self();
    args->large_serial_number = serial_number;
    args->my_name = name;

    //  Create the thread, passing the args pointer from heap
    int rc = pthread_create(thread, NULL, &_fun_thread_run, args);
    if (0 == rc) {
        // We return here, all is well, no stack data leak, args in heap
        return thread;
    } else {
        free(args);
        return NULL;
    }
}

// ...

// Elsewhere, start some threads!
pthread_t fun_thread1;
pthread_t fun_thread2;

_launch_fun_thread(&fun_thread1, 0xABCDEF12345678ULL, "super FUN thread 1");
usleep(500UL * 1000UL);
_launch_fun_thread(&fun_thread2, 0xDEADBEEF55AA55ULL, "super FUN thread 2");

pthread_join(fun_thread1, NULL);
pthread_join(fun_thread2, NULL);
// ...
```

For your particular example of an `unsigned long long`, you could have just allocated it instead of a struct:

```
unsigned long long *thread_arg = calloc(1, sizeof(*thread_arg));
*thread_arg = 123456;
```

Then passed it:

```
pthread_create(thread, NULL, &_fun_thread_run, (void *)thread_arg);
```

The `free()` would be done in same place, and you can cast from `void *` to `unsigned long long *` in your thread runner.

See https://gist.github.com/tcarmelveilleux/967728df33215d66e2e126637270901c for a full single-file-compilable example.